# "return" from method while stepping?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, lldb

I would like to exit out the current method that I'm stepping through.

```
-(void)helloWorld {
    NSLog(@"Hello");
    // I would like to return here, so that "World" isn't printed.
    NSLog(@"World");  
}
```

I have tried the following, but without luck.

```
(lldb) expr return
<no result>
```

Is this possible with lldb?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you are debugging using Xcode and when your program is paused at a breakpoint, you can drag the little green arrow to any other line in the function. E.g. in the following code:

[image: Xcode breakpoint]

if I want to skip the `NSLog(@"B")`,  I can simply drag the green arrow from line 20 to line 23, which means the function will simply "return" from anywhere I want.

Comment: I have seen several people report that under LLDB and ARC, dragging the PC to a new location can cause crashes. There are still some kinks to be worked out. Also, if you are familiar with GDB, but not LLDB, save a copy of this cheat sheet: http://lldb.llvm.org/lldb-gdb.html

Comment: Yeah, in general dragging the pc around is very risky unless you understand all of the runtime / memory allocation / initialization going on behind the scenes.  If you have a series of simple statements you can often get away with it but anything more sophisticated and it is fraught with hidden gotchas.

Answer (score 21):

Unfortunately in Xcode 4.5.x there is no way to force an early return from a function.  In the current lldb sources over at http://lldb.llvm.org/ there is a newly added command, `thread return`, which does what you want - it includes the ability to specify the return value of the function.  This won't be in Xcode until the next major release, though.

Answer (score 0):

I just added a breakpoint at the line mentioned below:

```
var computed: Bool { 
   return device.time == 10 // added breakpoint here
}
```

and got the following error:

> error: Error returning from frame 0 of thread 1: We only support
>   setting simple integer and float return types at present..

Seems to work for only those two types