# How to make current stack frame return when debugging with lldb?

Tags: debugging, lldb

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“return” from method while stepping?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12872167/return-from-method-while-stepping)

When debugging a process using gdb and the target is suspended, the return command makes gdb return immediately from the current stack frame (without executing the rest of the current function).

How can I achieve the same effect in lldb?

I tried 'return' and 'frame return', but lldb just tells me that these are not 'known' commands. I'm using the lldb integrated in Xcode 4.5.1 (LLDB-167.4).

Comment: @MartinR Possibly yes, even though I (obviously ;) think that my question is better phrased and can be found more easily... http://stackoverflow.com/a/12876959/118854 seems to be the answer I'm looking for.

Comment: Yes, Jason Molenda seems to know everything about lldb :-)

Answer (score 0):

According to https://stackoverflow.com/a/12876959/118854, this is possible with lldb built from HEAD (using a new command `thread return`), but is not possible in versions of Xcode 4.5.x.